# MySQL Update Field with some prefix

Tags: mysql

i have table have prefixed with `bok-` and `inv-`

```
id | number
1  | bok-1
2  | inv-3
3  | bok-2
4  | inv-2
5  | inv-10
6  | bok-3
```

How can it sorted the field `number` prefixed with `inv-`?
Which in this case the result will be:

```
id | number
1  | bok-1
2  | inv-1
3  | bok-2
4  | inv-2
5  | inv-3
6  | bok-3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use MySQL's [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function:

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(number, 5) AS SIGNED)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e79a5/1/0).

However, it would probably be better to store the prefix and integer parts in separate columns, if at all possible:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
  ADD COLUMN prefix ENUM('bok', 'inv'),
  ADD COLUMN suffix INT;

UPDATE mytable SET
  prefix = LEFT(number, 3),
  suffix = SUBSTRING(number, 5);

ALTER TABLE mytable
  DROP COLUMN number;
```

Comment: i didn't understand what you do on sqlfiddle, there is change i see in there @_@

Comment: The script that you make in sqlfiddle, i didn't see any update done in there. i just see you sorted the number.

Comment: @GusDeCooL: Oh, I didn't realise you wanted to *update* the table.  This suggests a possible misunderstanding or design flaw - can you provide more detail around *why* you're trying to accomplish this?

Comment: i had 2 database with same structure and it will be export import. on the import version database. There will be some gap on the numbering. And i want to fix that gap `number`.

Comment: @GusDeCooL: Gaps in `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns are nothing to worry about.

Comment: the `number` field didn't have `auto_increment`

Comment: @GusDeCooL: I was referring to the `id` column.

Comment: yes, but what i want to remove the gap is the `number` not the `id`

Comment: @GusDeCooL: Clearly I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to accomplish.  You do realise that MySQL tables are not stored in a sorted order?  You only achieve sorted results by applying an `ORDER BY` clause when retrieving data.  Therefore, you will always need to do as I suggest above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13241/discussion-between-eggyal-and-gusdecool)

Comment: please see the example for the result that i expected. Sorry if it hard to understand @_@

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should redesign your database structure. Unfortunately no other options possible processing this efficiently since the database won't index on those dashes. So separate both in 2 fields is the most common practice. Otherwise you will run table scans on every order by clause.

Edit: In addition to the information from the discussion you had: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13241/discussion-between-eggyal-and-gusdecool it is clear that this is a wrong design and the operation you are asking for should not be executed at all.

It would be both impossible to realize it without created a decent structure and to create a solution this way which would be legally ok.

Comment: i not allowed to redesign the database structure

Comment: Then your only option is to do something ugly in your query or keep a separate index somewhere else. That's about it. I may not be a wrong decision but make sure you know why you make it. If you are not allowed to change structure you would have to. Though it would implicate performance issues possibly in the future on your database.